Flutter Local Push Notification Custom Vibration
Custom notification vibration pattern in Flutter Local Push Notification doesn't work.
Setup a notification channel or details, the vibration pattern not work
AndroidNotificationChannel(
    "DEFAULT",
    "DEDAULT",
    description: "Default notifications",
    importance: Importance.high,
    enableLights: true,
    enableVibration: false,
    vibrationPattern: Int64List.fromList([250, 250, 250, 250]),
    playSound: true,
  );

AndroidNotificationDetails(
      NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.id,
      NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.name,
      channelDescription: NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.description,
      importance: NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.importance,
      enableLights: NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.enableLights,
      enableVibration: NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.enableVibration,
      vibrationPattern: NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.vibrationPattern,
      playSound: NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.playSound,
      sound: NotificationChannels.defaultChannel.sound,
      priority: Priority.high,
      additionalFlags: Int32List.fromList([4]),
    )

when call notification.show() with the channel & details above. the custom vibration pattern is not work.
